# Display colorbox for legend in ipywidgets

Tags: python, html, css, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

for a legend of a model I made in ipyvolume, I wanted to make a widget.HTML which displays a little colorbox besides the corresponding label in a widgets.HTML().

As I see you can only put a single string line for the html code. Does somebody have a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just build a grid and color buttons in the wanted colors:

```
def create_expanded_button(description):
    return Button(description=description, style={'font_weight': 'bold'}, layout=Layout( width='auto'))

def color_box (description, color):
    b1 = Button(description=description)
    b1.style.button_color = color
    return b1


# names and colors are two lists of length 11 and 22

cgrid = GridspecLayout(12, 2)
tgrid = GridspecLayout(12, 1)

c = 0
for i in range(12):
        for j in range(2):
                cgrid[i, j] = color_box(''.format(i, j), colors[c])
                c+=1 
     
            
for i in range(12):
        for j in range(1):
            tgrid[i, j] = create_expanded_button(names[i-1].format(i, j))
 
        
grid = GridspecLayout(2, 2, height='auto', width='auto')
grid[:, :1] = cgrid
grid[:, 1:] = tgrid
grid
```